# upload a file and save it in a temporary folder

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method that uploads a file:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {

        string directory = @"C:\Temp\";

        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and here is my ajax call:

```
$('#uploadButton').on('click', function()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Application")',
        timeout: 2000,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {

            //show content
            alert('Success!')
        }
    });
}
)
```

I need to send the "Request.files["file"]" with the uploaded file.

Here is the form where my code is located :

```
<form action="/profile/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">

        <label>File</label>

        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="uploadButton" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What language is your server side code written an? Please add a tag for it.

Comment: can you change the contentType of the request and try , i didnt see how you are reading files as well in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
    $('#uploadButton').on('click', function () {
    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $('[type="file"]').get(0).files;
    // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("file", files[0]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Application")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //show content
            alert('Success!')
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];  returned null

Comment: check this Request.Files[0]